# Wait until div of class opacity-transition is available in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I want to wait until div of class  opacity-transition is available in selenium python, so to execute this I tried:-

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibilityOfAllElements((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='reports-content opacity-transition fade']")))
```

Where I got the error:-

> WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibilityOfAllElements((By.XPATH, "//
> div[@class='reports-content opacity-transition fade']")))
> AttributeError: module
> 'selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions' has no a ttribute
> 'invisibilityOfAllElements'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, Selenium with Python has only `invisibility_of_element_located` expected condition dealing with element(s) invisibility.
So you should use

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(your_element_locator)
```

See the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)